# How to set up a questionaire template using JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to set up a small question/answer quiz and I'm wondering if this is a good way of going about it -

should I make it an array of objects?

```
export const questions = [
  {
    question: "What is the 2nd planet in our solar system?",
    choices: [
      "Earth",
      "Saturn",
      "Venus",
      "Neptune"
    ],
    answer: "Venus"
  },
  {
    question: "True or False: Mars has four moons",
    choices: [
      "True",
      "False"
    ],
    answer: "False"
  }
]
```

I'm gonna use this in my app to show a card and a radio button to click the right answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you send the answers to the client they could potentially cheat.

Comment: oh.  what's a good way to avoid that :D

Comment: Don't send the answers to the client; remove the "answer" property.

Comment: how do I compare the answers in that case?  Will I have to add a questionID and AnswerID that corresponds to it?  Sorry i want to make sure do this right.

Comment: I would maintain a list of answers on the server side and insert some sort of id like you said and then just return true or false as result to the client.

Comment: thanks!  that makes sense.  also, since choices will always be strings (that will mapped out to radio buttons), is it fine to keep choices as array?